# How to get how much data application have download?

Tags: iphone, streaming

My application is streaming live video, I want to alert them for after every 100MB download.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want,data received throgh NSURlConnection.

Comment: Not through NSURLConnection but when I doing live streaming using MPMoviePlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily because MPMoviePlayer internals doesn't reveal metadata about the stream.

If you actually knew for certain the data FPS and resolution (or bitrate for audio), using the elapsed time you could do an adhoc calculation by dividing them.